# Check if array is inside a string

Tags: php, arrays

```
$comment = 'billie jean is not my lover she is just a girl';
$words = array('jean','lover','jean');
$lin = some_function_name($comment,$words);
($lin=3)
```

I tried `substr_count()`, but it doesn't work on array. Is there a builtin function to do this?

Comment: Is `some_function_name` supposed to return how many strings from `$words` were matched?

Comment: i think he wants to know if all items in the array are in the string provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `array_filter().`  This will work in PHP >= 5.3.  For a lower version, you'll need to handle your callback differently.

```
$lin = sum(array_filter($words, function($word) use ($comment) {return strpos($comment, $word) !== false;}));
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a simpler approach with more lines of code:

```
function is_array_in_string($comment, $words)
{
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($comment as $item)
    {
        if (strpos($words, $item) !== false)
            count++;
    }
    return $count;
}
```

[array_map](http://pt.php.net/array_map) would probably produce a much cleaner code.

Answer (score 1):

using `array_intersect` & `explode`:

to check all there:

```
count(array_intersect(explode(" ", $comment), $words)) == count($words)
```

count:

```
count(array_unique(array_intersect(explode(" ", $comment), $words)))
```

Comment: Wouldn't this unnecessarily guzzle memory? (exploding the entire comment string.)

Comment: because we're searching for words, I thought of transforming the $comment to separate words (space delimited) before the search. Otherwise, with strpos & co functions, 'jean' will be found in 'billie jean' & 'billiejean'

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be surprised if I get downvoted for using regex here, but here's a one-liner route:

```
$hasword = preg_match('/'.implode('|',array_map('preg_quote', $words)).'/', $comment);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a closure (works just with PHP 5.3):

```
$comment = 'billie jean is not my lover she is just a girl';
$words = array('jean','lover','jean');
$lin = count(array_filter($words,function($word) use ($comment) {return strpos($comment,$word) !== false;}));
```

Or in a simpler way:

```
$comment = 'billie jean is not my lover she is just a girl';
$words = array('jean','lover','jean');
$lin = count(array_intersect($words,explode(" ",$comment)));
```

In the second way it will just return if there's a perfect match between the words, substrings won't be considered.